# Pico Pi giving synthax error on pillow library

Tags: sd-card, pi-pico

I am running a main.py file on the Pico Pi that imports a test file in a SD card that is connected by a module. The test.py file then imports PIL from the same directory as the file. I believe this should work but when the program runs, it gives me a synthax error and points to a file from the Pillow library.

Here is how my files are placed:

[image]

...

[image]

Here is the main.py code which is the first file to run:

```
import machine
import sdcard
import uos

import sys

cs = machine.Pin(1, machine.Pin.OUT)

spi = machine.SPI(0,
                  baudrate=1000000,
                  polarity=0,
                  phase=0,
                  bits=8,
                  firstbit=machine.SPI.MSB,
                  sck=machine.Pin(2),
                  mosi=machine.Pin(3),
                  miso=machine.Pin(4))

sd = sdcard.SDCard(spi, cs)

vfs = uos.VfsFat(sd)
uos.mount(vfs, "/sd")

sys.path.append("/sd/rainy project/rainy")

import test
```

Here is the test.py code which gets imported by the main.py file:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.new("1", (100,100))
```

And finally, here is the error message that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 26, in <module>
  File "/sd/rainy project/rainy/test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/sd/rainy project/rainy/PIL/Image.py", line 110
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It is as if there was an error at line 110 in the PIL library which seems weird and when I looked at line 110 in the Image.py file, nothing was wrong.

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: What about the quotes around the right parenthesis: `')'` ?

Comment: @Dirk Which one are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, by removing the block in the pillow Image.py file that was causing my error, I found out that there was an underlying problem. I am using all of my Pico's memory. This is probably the reason why it was giving me this error message.